# Release client hangs forever when server has issue (may be socket reset) during calling hessian

Tags: java, networking, release, freeze, hessian

I have a client calls to a server through Hessian. During that time the server is not stable and ussually have Socket reset error. And the client was hangs at the below log. So how can I release this log but still keep the application running. And what is the reason that make the client hang forever? Thanks

> at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       - locked <0x2159c988> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

Comment: which implementation of Hessian?

Comment: I suppose that's spring.... :|

Comment: are you sure the network is working OK? maybe it's a network reliability problem.

Comment: The network seem fine. But I am not sure. Why the client was blocked forever? However, their is another thread in the client application was still able to connect to that server normally after that.

Answer (score 1):

By default HttpUrlConnection has no timeouts.
You need to set java system properties for this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout (default: -1)
sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout (default: -1)
```

Set it from command line:

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=30000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=30000
```

Or from Java code:

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "30000");
System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "30000");
```